# String Array data not showing in TextView

Tags: java, android

I'm in the process of learning android app development however I have come to an impasse.  My RecyclerView is picking up how many items are in my String array however it is not showing the actual data in text1, any help would be much appreciated.

This is my adapter

```
public class EventCalenderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EventCalenderAdapter.ViewHolder> {

static String[] fakeData = new String[] {
        "One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Ah..Ah..Ah"
};

static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CardView cardView;
    TextView titleView;

    public ViewHolder(CardView card) {
        super(card);
        cardView = card;
        titleView = (TextView) card.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    }
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int i) {
    CardView v = (CardView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.event_task, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    viewHolder.titleView.setText(fakeData[i]);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return fakeData.length;
}
```

This is the corresponding XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:event_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/event_view"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/task_card_half_spacing"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/task_card_half_spacing"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/gutter"
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/gutter"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:elevation="@dimen/task_card_elevation"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
event_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium.Inverse"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Inverse"
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text1"/>


</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and this is my fragment

```
public class EventCalenderFragment extends Fragment {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
EventCalenderAdapter adapter;


public EventCalenderFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    adapter = new EventCalenderAdapter();
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_event_calender, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm... everything looks ok, can you try setting this to it:

```
android:textColor="#000000"
```